# PayPal Express Checkout API Callback

Tags: api, paypal, ios6, express-checkout

I'm working with the express checkout API for a simple cart.  I use the callback parameter to provide a secure URL that PayPal should hit expecting both shipping options and tax rates in return. On a desktop browser this process works as expected, however it does not hit the callback URL when tested on a mobile browser, particularly iOS 6.  Any ideas? PayPal tech support doesn't have any.

Thanks,
Howie

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware the mobile Express Checkout and Payments Standard flows don't currently support the Instant Update Callback API.
At least definitely for PayPal Payments Standard; https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-paypal-payments-standard

> Unsupported Use Cases Mobile PayPal Payments Standard is in the
>   process of extending support for the merchant customizations listed
>   below. Until then your customers will still be able to make payments
>   via mobile devices but will not be presented with the mobile optimized
>   checkout experience. For now only merchants integrated with 'Buy Now'
>   buttons or third party shopping carts (using “Cart Upload”) will
>   benefit from Mobile PayPal Payments Standard unless they use a
>   customization listed below.
>
> Merchant Customizations that are currently not supported:
>
> **Instant Update API**